# Affordable pi like computer for robot

Tags: raspberry-pi, usb

I have raspberry pi in a robot but it seems sdcard is not reliable at all.

What are affordable options that could be considered reliable? Pi+USB Flash, Pi+USB SSD, Pi compute module with eMMC, BeegleBoard with eMMC?

May be there is some reliable SD card brand or USB_Flash?

I would say my budget is up to $350 and I need linux computer with performance of Pi3 and 2-4 USB ports + IO

It seems to me right now that Pi+USB_Good_Brand_SSD is most reliable option. But may be I miss something.

Comment: probably all of the ones you listed

Comment: What do you mean by "not reliable"? I have been using pi for a long time but never had a problem with SD unless I cut the power while the pi is writing a file to SD. Pi has multiple background processes that writes files to SD. So if you cut the power without parking it, it will be corrupted.

Comment: @C.OPark I had lots of dead sdcards: Samsung, SanDisk and chinese no name. May be some of brand sdcards are fake. But I have no idea how to ensure I will get real brand sdcard. It seems USB Flash is often more reliable than sdcard and good brand SSD is much more reliable than the rest.

Comment: I would recommend trying a read-only mode if possible.

Another solution is using a high endurance sd card which is originally dedicated to a dashcam.

Answer (score 1):

The Argon One case has a USB 3.0 M.2 adapter for the raspberry pi 4. So, you could use an SSD instead of an SD card, if that is where you're having issues.

https://www.argon40.com/argon-one-m-2-case-for-raspberry-pi-4.html